# How to call a return Task in a blazor component

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I don't know if the title is corrent. Please help, I am new in blazor. I want to call a Task function on the blazor component, I want it to be called inside a foreach loop,** not by a click event**.

The thing is, i want a fullname of an employee from the employee table that is linked to person table.**The Task GetFullName(int deviceId) return a fullName as a string.** I used a **Id from device table** to get a device from loaned table which have a device table. I get to see the name in the console but not displaying on the table.

## Blazor.razor

```
<table class="table custom-table">
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Full Name</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

   @foreach (var device in DeviceService.device){
      GetFullName(device.Id) ;  //error ?

      @FullName  //John Smith
   }
   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
@code{

  
private string FullName = string.Empty;

  private async Task<string> EmployeeWithDevice(int deviceId)
    {
        //get loan dvice from database by using deviceId'
        var result = await DeviceLoanService.GetDeviceLoanById(deviceId);

        var Loan = result.Data;

        if (result.Success)
        {
            FullName = $"{Loan?.Employee?.Person?.FirstName}, {Loan?.Employee?.Person?.LastName}";
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(FullName);

        return FullName;

        
    }
}
```

Comment: These code samples do not link up. Read about posting a [mre]

Answer (score 3):

The code in the markup section cannot be async.

Prepare your data in the proper event:

```
@code {
  List<string> fullNames = new();

  override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
     fullNames = await ... ;  // some async code to get your data
  }

}
```

and then it is just

```
  @foreach(string fullName in fullNames)
  {
    @fullName
  }
```

Comment: I have modified my repository (DeviceService), to do the operation of getting the employee name since the markup section cannot be async. now am getting the name from the repository. it's working fine. thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your code correctly, this should be the right code you need:

```html
<table class="table custom-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Full Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    @foreach (var name in _fullNames)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@name</td>
        </tr>
    }

</tbody>
</table>

@code {

private List<string> _fullNames = new();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    @foreach (var device in DeviceService.device)
    {
        var fullName = await EmployeeWithDevice(device.id);
        _fullNames.Add(fullName);
    }
}

private async Task<string> EmployeeWithDevice(int deviceId)
{
    //get loan dvice from database by using deviceId'
    var result = await DeviceLoanService.GetDeviceLoanById(deviceId);

    var loan = result.Data;

    var fullName = string.Empty;

    if (result.Success)
    {
        fullName = $"{Loan?.Employee?.Person?.FirstName}, {loan?.Employee?.Person?.LastName}";
    }

    //Console.WriteLine(FullName);

    return fullName;
}
}
```

Comment: After `var fullName = EmployeeWithDevice(device.Id);` fullName will be a Task, not a string.

Comment: My bad to miss await. Update the code snippet now.

Comment: But you cannot `await` there. This won't compile.

Comment: You are right. I have updated the code to load the full names on component initialization and then print that list in HTML table.